# Gate to or gate for

Tags: meaning, expressions

When I want to say that our services is the next move or if you want to get modern technology use our services, should I say, "Your gate ***to*** modern technology" or "Your gate ***for*** modern technology"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither reads particularly well (I wouldn't expect to see either), though "gate to" would fit best. However, I think the phrase you are looking for is:

> Your **gateway** to modern technology.